# Sending Non Multipart data Via RestSharp

Tags: c#, http, dll, restsharp

I need to send A POST request that can not be multi-part data, every answer I have seen so far  has been to change the http.cs file for RestSharp, but I am not familiar with how to go about this.

My code:

```
        var POST_LTFSclient = new RestClient("https://xxxx");
        var POST_LTFSrequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        POST_LTFSrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Token " + Token);
        POST_LTFSrequest.AddHeader("Accept", "Application/xml");
        POST_LTFSrequest.AddHeader("Content-type", "Application/xml");
        POST_LTFSrequest.AddFile("content", @"C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.xml");
```

The last line cannot be just:

```
        POST_LTFSrequest.AddFile(@"C:\xxx\xxx\xxx.xml");
```

but because of this every attempt to send Data is always Multi-part.
Unfortunately the receiving party do not accept this.

Is there anyway to get around this that is easy to implement, if not could some one explain to me how I change Restsharp to allow this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that because RestSharp has changed so much, the answers I have found are all out dated...

I was unable to find anymore information on this issue, so I have had to move away from restSharp.

The solution I have come up with is as follows:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token " + Token);
            using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\xxx\yyy\zzz.xml"))
            using (Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri("https://xxx/yyy/zzz"), "POST"))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            }

        }
```